# How to make a button float next to the input form?

Tags: html, css

I have the following form, and my button is an image button. I want in to be on the same line with the email input but I cannot figure out how to accomplish it. I made my button float towards the right but it is not aligned on the same line with the input field.

Form:

```css
 .control-group{
    float:left;
    }

    .control-group.button{
    clear:both;
    }
```

```html
<form class="well email-form" id="emailForm" name="sendEmail" novalidate="" method="post">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="control-group">
   <div class="field-control">
     <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email-address" type="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" required="" data-validation-required-message=" "/>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="control-group button">
   <div class="field-control">
  <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/25x25" name="submitEmail" class="button"/>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.control-group{
float:left;
}

.control-group.button{
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the clear?

Comment: it worked, I thought that since div is a block I had to use clear to align it side by side

Comment: Clearing an element means that it will moved down below a floated element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: bottom` like:

```css
 .control-group {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 input[type="image"].button {
   vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

```html
<form class="well email-form" id="emailForm" name="sendEmail" novalidate="" method="post">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="field-control">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email-address" type="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" required="" data-validation-required-message=" " />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group button">
      <div class="field-control">
        <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/25x25" name="submitEmail" class="button" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are classes built into bootstrap to do this. You can add the `form-inline` class to your form and replace your `control-group` class with `form-group`. This way you don't have to create any custom css to do the alignment. You also don't need the `field-control` class/div unless that's part of your custom css.

```
<form class="well email-form form-inline" id="emailForm" name="sendEmail" novalidate="" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="field-control">
                <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email-address" type="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" required="" data-validation-required-message=" " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="field-control">
                <input type="image" src="images/tree.png" name="submitEmail" class="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to wrap under `<span>` tag

**Fiddle**

**http://jsfiddle.net/m4rz38h7/2/**

```
   .control-group{
    display:inline-block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        vertical-align:top;  
    }

    .button{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }
```